# iPhone - Itunes store status always show waiting for upload?

Tags: iphone, app-store, itunes-store

I have successfully submitted the app for iTunes store for 3 hours ago. But status in iTunes store always showing "Waiting for upload". 
This are the steps i did for submitting the app to iTunes store.
1. Product -> Archive
2. Organizer -> Validate(validation successful) -> Submit.
After submit i got the message that app validated successful and submitted to iTunes store. But still the status shows "Waiting for upload". What will be the reason for this.

Comment: Which ios version u r using.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the link you can follow... a step by step Guide... Hope it helps to you.

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/

this is the Old way of submitting apps, if you any problem please let me know. but if it helps kindly accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Really weird... Normally it should change the statut instantly after the upload.

What happens if you try to upload your app again ?

(Archive -> Organizer -> Distribute -> Submit)

Comment: @Asbbay thank you. I submitted second time also. But no use. One more thing i am using xcode 4.1 and this doesn't contain distribute button. Direct submit button.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any solution... :S maybe try to wait a few more minutes or hours and contact the support...   Reading this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1605273?start=0&tstart=0 it seems that recreating the entire project may work.